# How to combine multiple lists into a single list?

Tags: python-3.x, sorting

I have a list, let's call it `combinedLists`, which contains `n`-elements that are each a list of dict objects. The number of dicts in each list of `combinedLists` is usually not the same (but could be), i.e.:

```
len(combinedLists) = 2
type(combinedLists[0]) = list
type(combinedLists[0][0]) = dict
len(combinedLists[0]) = 250
type(combinedLists[1]) = list
type(combinedLists[1][0]) = dict
len(combinedLists[1]) = 400
```

Each dict object has a `tstamp` key which gives a datetime object value. The lists are already in chronological order such that the dict at index 0 is always the most recent timestamp, and the last dict is the earliest.

What I want to do is:

- combine each list element of `combinedLists` into a single list (let's call it `consolidatedList`) of dict objects that are in chronological order where index `0` is the most recent dict, i.e. so that `consolidatedList[0]['tstamp']` is most recent and `consolidatedList[-1]['tstamp']` would be the earliest.

I keep re-writing the algorithm. I need some advice how to implement this if you will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work as long as your datetime objects are recognized by Python's `list.sort()` function. It seemed to work for me with both `datetime` and `time` libraries.

```
from operator import itemgetter

consolidatedlist = [d for list_of_dicts in combinedlist for d in list_of_dicts]
consolidatedlist.sort(key=itemgetter('tstamp'))
```